# How to interpret cosine similarity output in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cosine-similarity

beginner @ Python here.
I have a pandas DataFrame **df** with the columns: **userID**, **weight**, **SEI**, **name**.

```
#libraries 
   import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
   from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
    
#dataframe
   userID    weight     SEI        name
   3         125.0.     0.562140   263
   4         254.0.     0.377294   869 
   5         451.0.     0.872896   196
   1429      451.0.     0.872896   196 
   5         129.0.     0.569432   582
   ...       ...        ...        ...

#output
   cosine_similarity(df)

   array([[1.        , 0.98731894, 0.75370844, ..., 0.33814175, 0.33700687, 0.24443919],
   [0.98731894, 1.        , 0.63987877, ..., 0.35037059, 0.34963404, 0.23870279],
   [0.75370844, 0.63987877, 1.        , ..., 0.16648431, 0.16403693, 0.17438159], 
   ...,
```

The person with **userID** 3 has a **weight** of 125.0, and **SEI** of 0.562140. The person with **name** 263 also has a **weight** of 125.0, and **SEI** of 0.562140. (*I had to use a label encoder for the **name** column because I could not run the cosine similarity function without changing the column data type. Hopefully this doesn't affect the end goal?*)

The goal is to match up values from the column **userID** to values in the column **name** using cosine similarity on all rows. I just need some guidance in interpreting the output in order to do this. All I know is the higher the cosine value the greater the similarity.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it easier for yourself and group by two columns

```
result1=df.sort_values('weight')
result2=(result1.groupby(['userID_x','SEI']).apply(lambda g: 
         cosine_similarity(g['weight'].values.reshape(1, -1), 
         g['artist'].values.reshape(1,-1))[0][0])).rename('CosSim').reset_index()
```